# Set hidden textField on Tap gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

Hide and show textField on tap gesture.

Here is code :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ShowBASEURL)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 3;
[_txtBaseUrl addGestureRecognizer:tap];

- (void)ShowBASEURL
{
    _txtBaseUrl.hidden = NO;
}


- (void)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    _txtBaseUrl.hidden = YES;
}
```

It's not working because after hiding textField, the tap gesture is not working.
Is there any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you are hiding _txtBaseUrl instance. User Interaction will be disable at that time.Gesture will not work.

change this line and try

```
[_txtBaseUrl addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

to

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

check your delegate method you assign as wrong

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
_txtBaseUrl.hidden = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are hiding _txtBaseUrl instance. User choose 2 option for that
 1) User Interaction will be disable at that time. Gesture will not work.
 2) you are hiding _txtBaseUrl instance

Code like that :

```
- (void)ShowBASEURL {

[_txtTesting resignFirstResponder];

// if hide the _txtBaseUrl
_txtTesting.hidden = YES;

// if not hide the _txtBaseUrl and gesture are disable
//  _txtTesting.hidden = NO;
// _txtTesting.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In textFieldShouldEndEditing,you are hiding _txtBaseUrl instance. User Interaction will be disable at that time. So,Gesture will not work in this case.